# how to remove special price label and display regular price and special price in same line in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7

I have a requirement to remove special price label and display special price and regular price on the same line in in feature slider in Magento home page if its possible from admin side then say first because I am not  Magento developer,

thanks.

like below image
[image]

Comment: NO its not possible form admin

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible from admin you have to change html layout and css.